# Substract a vector with each element in that vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
df 
#   a b
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
# 3 3 5
```

And now for each column I want to create a second data.frame df2 that substracts all elements of a column from each other like this:

```
df2
#   c  d  e
# 1 0 -1 -2
# 2 1  0 -1
# 3 2  1  0
```

### data

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3),
                 b=c(3, 4, 5))

df2 <- data.frame(c=c(1 - 1, 2 - 1, 3 - 1),
                  d=c(1 - 2, 2 - 2, 3 - 2),
                  e=c(1 - 3, 2 - 3, 3 - 3))
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(outer(df$a, df$a, '-'))`. Or even `lapply(df, function(x) as.data.frame(outer(x, x, '-')))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base data frame `d2_2`

```
(df2_2 <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, 1:3)))
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  2  2  2
# 3  3  3  3
```

Then subtract columns of `df` from `df2_2` using `sweep` in `lapply`.

```
lapply(df, \(x) sweep(df2_2, 2, x))
# $a
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  0 -1 -2
# 2  1  0 -1
# 3  2  1  0
# 
# $b
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1 -2 -3 -4
# 2 -1 -2 -3
# 3  0 -1 -2
```